# iOS: Making an App terminate when leave screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I've build a simple app activating something in hardware, not important.

Now I just want the app to terminate completely if the user leaves the screen, switches apps, gets a call, press the home button, etc.

I'm all mixed up by all the application states, I couldn't find the right place to handle it.
I guess I need to listen to an "going to sleep" event and put a termination command (exit!)
or something like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easier than what one might think.

In your app's plist file define (check) the option "Application does not run in background" (`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`), and you are done.

[image]